# Contact form 7 telephone number verification

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I am trying to use the built in verification method for contact form 7 to verify a telephone number.

**Contact form 7 markup:**

```
<p>[number* your-telephone min:1000000000 max:9999999999 placeholder "Telephone number"] </p>

<p>[submit "submit"]</p>
```

So, what I am trying to do here is restrict phone number using the min and max properties of input type of number. But the problem here is that if I enter a telephone number say: 0402356584 then it is less than the min value but is still a phone number.

So, how can I set the min and max value to support all possible 10 digit telephone numbers?

Any other solution different from my approach is also most welcome. Because I have got a feeling that the verification can not be done using min and max attributes.

I also tried to edit the plugin files via functions.php file by using the code from a [source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/number-phone-validation-for-contact-form-7-doing-it-manually) but that did not work.

So, if any one has the perfect solution to validate telephone numbers on contact form 7 then please post your answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this one definitely it will work as per [contact form 7 documentation](https://contactform7.com/number-fields/).

```
[number* your-telephone minlength:10 maxlength:140 placeholder "Telephone number"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Gave me the idea that minlength and maxlength can be used to solve the case with ease. Please review my edit so that other people can find your answer useful.

Comment: Why is maxlength 140?

Comment: why number? it could be `[tel your-phone minlength:10 maxlength:140]`

Answer (score 16):

You can use **[tel* tel-672]** field and validate according to your requirement through  **wpcf7_is_tel** filter hook .

**Contact form 7** has many pre-defined hooks through which you can validate any field.Here, in the Contact Form 7 formatting.php module, validation rule is defined by following method .You can override it by filter hook  mentioned in apply_filters through functions.php

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
    $result = preg_match( '/^[+]?[0-9() -]*$/', $tel );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

Please add the below mentioned code in functions.php in your activated theme folder and add your validation rule to $result

```
// define the wpcf7_is_tel callback 
function custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel( $result, $tel ) { 
  $result = preg_match( '/^\(?\+?([0-9]{1,4})?\)?[-\. ]?(\d{10})$/', $tel );
  return $result; 
}

add_filter( 'wpcf7_is_tel', 'custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel', 10, 2 );
```

You can see [more](http://techiescircle.com/validate-telephone-field-length-contact-form-7/)

Comment: i want to restrict user to only add `123-123-1234` Format, Not '1234567890' or others, can i do this.? is ti possible by above hook

Comment: Yes above hook will be used to validate phone number type  of contact form 7.You have to just replace regular expression for this format "123-123-1234"

Answer (score 5):

In my case, below code is working.
Important point is that input type should be 'tel' as below.

```
[tel your-telephone minlength:1 maxlength:10]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for tel type fields. If you want to use number or text fields, you'll need to change 'wpcf7_validate_tel' in the filter param as well as the code.

```
function custom_phone_validation($result,$tag){

    $type = $tag->type;
    $name = $tag->name;

    if($type == 'tel' || $type == 'tel*'){

        $phoneNumber = isset( $_POST[$name] ) ? trim( $_POST[$name] ) : '';

        $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/[() .+-]/', '', $phoneNumber);
            if (strlen((string)$phoneNumber) != 10) {
                $result->invalidate( $tag, 'Please enter a valid phone number.' );
            }
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_tel','custom_phone_validation', 10, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_tel*', 'custom_phone_validation', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function custom_phone_validation($result,$tag){
        $type = $tag['type'];
        $name = $tag['name'];
        if($name == 'phonenumber'){
                    $phoneNumber = isset( $_POST['phonenumber'] ) ? trim( $_POST['phonenumber'] ) : '';
            $the_value = preg_match("/your_reg_exp format for phone number/",$_POST[$name]);
            if($phoneNumber == "" || $the_value == false ){ 
                $result->invalidate( $tag, "please enter vaild phone number" );
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_tel','custom_phone_validation', 10, 2);
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_tel*', 'custom_phone_validation', 10, 2);
```

phonenumber -> field name

try this one for function.php file.

Filter: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/trunk/modules/text.php `wpcf7_validate_tel` which is using the function `wpcf7_validate_tel( $result, $tag )`

Comment: Beware, if you are using a tel type in your form, change the filter params from wpcf7_validate_text to wpcf7_validate_tel

Comment: What should I put inside /your_reg_exp format for phone number/ and also I want to make set it minimum character to at least 10?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[tel your-phone minlength:10 maxlength:140]
```

good luck!!

chucha!

Comment: Can you pls share login behind this ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think i have nice workaround...

By the default the number field dont have minlength and maxlength validators.
**You can copy them from wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/text.php**

```
$atts['maxlength'] = $tag->get_maxlength_option();
$atts['minlength'] = $tag->get_minlength_option();
```

(in wpcf7_text_form_tag_handler function)... and validation filters

```
$code_units = wpcf7_count_code_units( stripslashes( $value ) );

if ( $maxlength && $maxlength < $code_units ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_too_long' ) );
} elseif ( $minlength && $code_units < $minlength ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_too_short' ) );
}
```

(in wpcf7_text_validation_filter function)

**And now paste it to the numbers.php in the right place.**
So in wpcf7_number_form_tag_handler function atts looks like:

```
$atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
$atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
$atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'signed_int', true );
$atts['min'] = $tag->get_option( 'min', 'signed_int', true );
$atts['max'] = $tag->get_option( 'max', 'signed_int', true );
$atts['step'] = $tag->get_option( 'step', 'int', true );
$atts['maxlength'] = $tag->get_maxlength_option();
$atts['minlength'] = $tag->get_minlength_option();
```

and wpcf7_number_validation_filter function ends with:

```
if ( $tag->is_required() && '' == $value ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
    } elseif ( '' != $value && ! wpcf7_is_number( $value ) ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_number' ) );
    } elseif ( '' != $value && '' != $min && (float) $value < (float) $min ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'number_too_small' ) );
    } elseif ( '' != $value && '' != $max && (float) $max < (float) $value ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'number_too_large' ) );
    } elseif ( $maxlength && $maxlength < $code_units ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_too_long' ) );
    } elseif ( $minlength && $code_units < $minlength ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_too_short' ) );
    }

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on other solutions, having a minimum length of 10 is preferred to ensure visitor include the area code in their submission. I've also allowed for 15 characters in case a visitor includes a country code and dashes "+1 555-555-5555"

```
[tel* your-phone minlength:10 maxlength:15]
```