# How can I validate phone number of all the countries in Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I have a WordPress website and use contact form 7 and I need the proper validation for the phone number of all the countries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried looking to similar questions here? Looks like this has a good suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425854/contact-form-7-telephone-number-verification. In case that doesn't fit your particular case, could you edit your question to include more details about your current setup? A code sample for what you have tried so far would help.